# Can I specify an aws policy based on a specific cognito field?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-policy

Can I apply a policy (for example to an AWS DynamoDB table) but restrict it based on a specific field of the Cognito user (other than the Cognito id)?

**What I'm tring to implement:**
I've got multiple Cognito users that belongs to one specific group. Each group can have multiple users. There are a lot of groups > 1000.

1. Each group should have permissions to read/write rows in a DynamoDB Table that belongs to the group (to do so the table has a field GroupName).
2. Each user should have the same permissions that the group he belongs to has.

I would like to check in the policy file that MyCognitoUser.GroupName equals the row.GroupName

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Amazon Cognito User Pools then you can use the recently launched [Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html) functionality to assign roles based on the user groups (you don't need to store this field in DynamoDB, instead it is part of user profile).